# Streaming DVDs from iCloud through AppleTV

Tags: appletv

I have an Apple TV and a bunch of DVDs that I want to rip and then stuck in the loft. I want to watch them via the AppleTV.

I’ve tried putting them in iTunes and that works but only while my PC is on. My thinking is that if I store them in the iCloud, surely there must be a way that I can then watch them on my Apple TV without needing an iTunes engine running elsewhere?

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no direct solutions. However, you could consider a service like Plex [(Link)](https://www.plex.tv/apps/streaming-devices/apple-tv/) this would allow you to create a Plex server with your media and stream it to several devices.

I have used plex for many years and it has worked perfectly for me. The service has some fees but they aren't massive and it will allow you to stream the content both to your tv and other apple devices with the Plex app.

You will need to bare in mind the CPU and GPU cost. Plex won't run well on a laptop you'll need a desktop of some form so Plex can transcode the videos for you to watch.

[Download Plex server here.](https://www.plex.tv/downloads/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to rip and store the DVD contents in iCloud. If the same content as in DVDs is available in iTunes Store, you can purchase it and stuck the DVDs in the loft. The purchased content is linked with your iCloud library and can be streamed directly via your Apple TV.

Comment: Well that’s not quite true, I have already done it, I just don’t want to leave the laptop running just to act as an iTunes server.